# Android and PHP sending incorrect numbers via JSON

Tags: php, android, json, random

I have PHP code that is creating a random number, setting that number in a database on my server, and then sending that number back to Android in a JSON response. I should also note that my PHP code is running on Google App Engine, but not sure if that matters or not. The problem is, even though I use the SAME PHP variable to set the value in the database that I send back to PHP in the JSON, the values are different. No idea how or why it's being changed.

Here's my PHP:

```
$load = rand(1, 100000000);
                $sql = "UPDATE game SET player1LoadedGame = 1, p1LoadedChangesTime = :loadChangesTime WHERE gameId = :gameId";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $params = array(
                    'gameId' => $_POST['gameId'],
                    'loadChangesTime' => $load
                );
                if($stmt->execute($params)) {
                    $data = array('success' => true, 'loadedTime' => strval($load)); 
                    echo (json_encode($data)); 
                } else {
                    // TODO: Should really undo inserts already done, but not worrying about it right now
                    $data = array('false' => false, "reason" => "Problem updating Game"); 
                    echo (json_encode($data)); 
                }
```

I've tried with and without the "loadedTime" property being wrapped in a call to strval function and it returns the same deal both times.

My Android:

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonCells", mazeJSON.toString()));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gameId", Integer.toString(gameId)));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player", Integer.toString(playerAccount.getPlayerId())));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
             JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
             if(object.getBoolean("success")) {
                 long result = mHelper.insertLoadTime(gameId, object.getLong("loadedTime"), playerAccount.getPlayerId());
                 if(result != -1) {
                     return true;
                 } else {
                     Log.e(TAG, "Problem inserting loadTime for Player1 on Game creation");
                    return false; 
                 }
             } else {
                return false; 
             }
```

Now obviously on each request the generated random number is going to be different, but on a particular attempt I check the db and I see the value:

31678233

However back in Android I'm passed back the value:

88914276

I can't for the life of me figure out why this would be happening.

**EDIT:**
I've even tried instead of using numbers do an md5 to the randomly generated number and return the value of the md5, and even that is being changed! What is going on!?

Comment: Did you try casting it to a long on the php end just before the json_encode? Edit: might not be possible...it was just a thought. Edit 2: use object.getInt instead of getLong?

Comment: Ugh, turns out this was actually a really stupid mistake. If I would have posted the rest of the PHP code you would have noticed this chunk of it is actually executing in a for loop and thus the value is being reset over and over again. I just moved all of this update and encode code out of the for loop,  put it after it, and everything is fixed.